# error in rake db:create command - Iniciando con Ruby on Rails

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

Estoy iniciando con Ruby on Rails. seguí esta guia de [GoRails](https://gorails.com/setup/windows/10), y llegué hasta el paso en donde hay que ejecutar el comando `rake db:create`,el cual me da un error.
el error indica que debo iniciar el servicio de postgres.
Bueno, instalé postgres e inicié el servicio, pero aun asi al abrir otra consola y volver a ejecutar el comando `rake db:create`, sigo con el mismo mensaje.
Inicio de servicio postgresql
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

console app
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

message
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se añada Contenido de config/database.yml

```
# PostgreSQL. Versions 9.3 and up are supported.
#
# Install the pg driver:
#   gem install pg
# On macOS with Homebrew:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
# On macOS with MacPorts:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
# On Windows:
#   gem install pg
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem 'pg'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_development

  # The specified database role being used to connect to postgres.
  # To create additional roles in postgres see `$ createuser --help`.
  # When left blank, postgres will use the default role. This is
  # the same name as the operating system user running Rails.
  #username: myapp

  # The password associated with the postgres role (username).
  #password:

  # Connect on a TCP socket. Omitted by default since the client uses a
  # domain socket that doesn't need configuration. Windows does not have
  # domain sockets, so uncomment these lines.
  #host: localhost

  # The TCP port the server listens on. Defaults to 5432.
  # If your server runs on a different port number, change accordingly.
  #port: 5432

  # Schema search path. The server defaults to $user,public
  #schema_search_path: myapp,sharedapp,public

  # Minimum log levels, in increasing order:
  #   debug5, debug4, debug3, debug2, debug1,
  #   log, notice, warning, error, fatal, and panic
  # Defaults to warning.
  #min_messages: notice

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_test

# As with config/credentials.yml, you never want to store sensitive information,
# like your database password, in your source code. If your source code is
# ever seen by anyone, they now have access to your database.
#
# Instead, provide the password or a full connection URL as an environment
# variable when you boot the app. For example:
#
#   DATABASE_URL="postgres://myuser:mypass@localhost/somedatabase"
#
# If the connection URL is provided in the special DATABASE_URL environment
# variable, Rails will automatically merge its configuration values on top of
# the values provided in this file. Alternatively, you can specify a connection
# URL environment variable explicitly:
#
#   production:
#     url: <%= ENV['MY_APP_DATABASE_URL'] %>
#
# Read https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-a-database
# for a full overview on how database connection configuration can be specified.
#
production:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_production
  username: postgres
  password: <%= ENV['MYAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Espero poder comenzar pronto a aprender ruby on rails!
Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrarnos el contenido de _config/database.yml_?

Comment: Claro @Gerry

Este es el contenido de este archivo:

default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_production
  username: postgres
  password: <%= ENV['MYAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer postgresql esta corriendo, te recomendaría lo siguiente, crea la base de datos manualmente entrando a la consola de postgres, esto usando el mismo comando que pusiste en la primera captura (`su -u postgres psql psql`), estando ya en la consola de postgres ejecutas:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE myapp_development;
CREATE USER user_my_app WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'superpassworddificil';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE myapp_development TO user_my_app;
```

Y cambiar la sección de development de tu database.yml por algo como

```yml
development:
  <<: *default
  database: myapp_development
  host: localhost
  user: user_my_app
  password: superpassworddificil
```

Comment: Hola @jaime-arroyo-navia 
creé la bas desde la consola de posgres:
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE myapp_development;
WARNING:  could not flush dirty data: Function not implemented
CREATE DATABASE
postgres=# CREATE DATABASE myapp_development;
ERROR:  database "myapp_development" already exists
postgres=# CREATE USER user_my_app WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'superpassworddificil';
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE myapp_development TO user_my_app;
GRANT
...
Me muestra este error al intentar abrir luego de rails server
`fe_sendauth: no password supplied`

te agradezco

Comment: Hola, me equivoqué en el database.yml en vez de pass era password, edité la respuesta.